# New relic Showing wrong RPM for transaction while selecting for longer ranges

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform, newrelic-synthetics

I am monitoring transaction throughput(RPM) for 7 days through New relic enterprise edition then it shows correct data but when I change date range for 3 months it shows wrong measurement for the same 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

We'll need more info to troubleshoot. I would suggest either opening a support ticket or asking the question on our developer forums at https://discuss.newrelic.com/ with details around the query you are using, some screenshots of what you see, etc. From there, we can look into your experience and help you further.

Comment: I got the answer of this behaviour.Aggregate metrics
Metric data aggregation depends on your subscription level.
Enterprise: Aggregates (averages) to 1-hour periods after 8 days. After 90 days the data further aggregates to daily values. This means you cannot obtain data granularity of less than 1 hour after 8 days, or less than daily values after 90 days.
Pro: After 8 days